# How to display UITableView according to day selected?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I have a tableview with 2 buttons, one button is for `today` and second button is for `yesterday` as follows along with following data where integer array for tDays representing value of weekdays like `Sunday = 1,....Saturday = 7`

```
var tAnimals:[String] = ["Cat", "Dog", "Rabbit"]
var tDays:[[Int]] = [[3,4],[4,5],[5,6]]

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var todayBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var yesterdayBtn: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int
{
    return tAnimals.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    myCell.titleLabel.text = "Animals"
    return myCell
}
}
```

Now when I press `todayBtn`, I like to see `Dog and Rabbit` in Table view as today is `Thursday = 5`, and I press `yestredayBtn`, I like to see `Cat and Dog` as it is `Wednesday = 4`.

I came across this extension for finding value of weekdays but have no idea how to apply it as button tags

```
extension Date {
    func dayNumberOfWeek() -> Int? {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekday], from: self).weekday
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can assign value of weekdays as button tags so that they update automatically everyday accordingly and display correct data.

Comment: You can set tags of button in viewDidLoad and then on button action set proper array and do tableview reload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this probably, might need some refractoring, I hope you'll get the basic idea:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

    var tAnimals:[String] = ["Cat", "Dog", "Rabbit"]
    var tDays:[[Int]] = [[3,4],[4,5],[5,6]]
    var arrdata:[String] = []
    var today:Int!
    var day:Int!

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var todayBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var yesterdayBtn: UIButton!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        today = Date().dayNumberOfWeek()
    }

    //connect this IBAction with todayBtn & yesterdayBtn
    @IBAction func actChangeData(_ sender: UIButton) {

        arrdata.removeAll()
        if sender == todayBtn {
            day = today
        } else {
            day = today - 1
        }

        for i in 0...tAnimals.count-1 {
           if tDays[i].contains(day) {
               arrdata.append(tAnimals[i])
            }
        }

        myTableView.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int {
        return arrdata.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        myCell.titleLabel.text = arrdata[indexPath.row]
        return myCell
    }
}

extension Date {
    func dayNumberOfWeek() -> Int? {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekday], from: self).weekday
    }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your response but I am getting same result Cat,Cat, Dog, Dog , Rabbit, Rabbit when I pressed both todayBtn and yesterdayBtn.

Comment: `func actChangeData(_ sender: UIButton)` updated with working code!

Comment: That works but is there anyway that I can display only that days data I mean when I  press todayBtn, I like to see dog and rabbit and I press yestredayBtn, I like to see cat and dog. But now the data is getting repeated   every time I pressed a button.

Comment: Yes, updated code with `arrdata.removeAll()` before every filteration.